# Como dividir um array e gravar no banco de dados em PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Possuo esse código:

```
<?php
    foreach ($_POST as $dados =>$value) {
    $list = explode('_', $value);
    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $list, TRUE ) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Ele gera a saída da array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Manoel da Silva
)

Array
(
    [0] => manel@gmail.com
)

Array
(
    [0] => (21)2481-3232
)

Array
(
    [0] => 41106
)

Array
(
    [0] => 21215430
)
```

Mas quero que a saída seja assim:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Manoel da Silva
)

Array
(
    [2] => manel@gmail.com
)

Array
(
    [3] => (21)2481-3232
)

Array
(
    [4] => 41106
)

Array
(
    [5] => 21215430
)
```

Após isso, quero gravar os valores no banco de dados, mas algo está dando errado:

```
$conn = conecta();

foreach ($_POST as $dados =>$value) {
    $cadastro = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO clientes(:nome) VALUES $value');
    $cadastro->bindValue(':nome', $value); //to colocando um valor só...
    $cadastro->execute();
}
```

Quero inserir as informações separadas no banco, como faço isso?

Comment: Qual é o output original? O formato do array que está a percorrer com o foreach? Dê um exemplo e melhore o display do código acima sff

Comment: Eu não entendi a pergunta  vc tem mais campos p colocar informação além do `nome`?

Comment: sim ray eu tenho 11 campos:, so não coloquei tudo para nao ficar muito extenso a pergunta:

Answer (score 2):

Ele gera essa saída indesejada porque está sempre a substituir o valor da `$list`, ou seja, vai sempre imprimir a $list gerada na linha anterior:

Creio que esta lógica será melhor:

```
$user = array();
foreach($_POST as $dado => $value) { // nota que mudei de dados para dado para ficar mais claro
   $list = explode('_', $value);
   $user[$dado] = $list[0]; // armazenamos cada dado (nome, telefone, etc..) dentro de um array
}
print_r($user);
```

Pode também inserir logo na base de dados:

```
foreach($_POST as $dado => $value) { // nota que mudei de dados para dado para ficar mais claro
    $cadastro = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO clientes(' .$dado. ') VALUES :' .$dado); // nota que a chave do post ($dado) deve ser igual ao nome da coluna que tem na tabela em que vai inserir isto
    $cadastro->bindValue(':' .$dado, $value); //to colocando um valor só...
    $cadastro->execute();

}
```

É de notar que esta não a forma mais segura de fazer isso

Comment: continua no array[0], todos os valores: 
Array
(
    [nome] => Array
        (
            [0] => Manoel
        )

    [email] => Array
        (
            [0] => lost@gmail.com
        )

)
cada array com um numero diferente e o q preciso.

Comment: Tem razão. Editei na parte do explode. Desculpe, assim já deve dar certo. Mas ao que é que está a fazer explode? Dê-me um exemplo. Não ponha `True` como segundo elemento do `print_r`

Comment: Estou usando explode para substituir split do mysql, na verdade eu quero "separar" os valores do array para poder inserir no bd. a saída agora está assim : Array ( [nome] => [email] => [telefone] => [servico] => 41106 [sCepDestino] => [num] => 48 [comp] => casa 1 ) , acho que agora dá pra inserir os dados separadamente, alguma sugestão no insert?

Comment: Não era o array nesse formato que queria? E se não puser o explode e deixar só `$user[$dado] = $value;`? Será isso que quer?

Answer (score 2):

Ao utilizar prepared statemens coloque as marcações(placeholders) na consulta, não passe os valores direto na sql e lembre nomes de colunas, tabelas não podem ser associados com placeholders apenas valores.

Código atual:

```
$cadastro = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO clientes(:nome) VALUES $value');
```

Para corrigir faça:

```
$cadastro = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO clientes(nome) VALUES :nome');
```

Para inserir todos os valores de forma mais pratica passe um array no `execute()` e use as interrogações como bind.

```
foreach($_POST as $dado => $value) {
   $valores = explode('_', $value);
   $binds = str_repeat('?,', 10) .'?';
   $cadastro = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO clientes(nome,email,telefone,servico,cep,tipo_logradouro,logradouro,numero,complemento,ba‌​irro,cidade,estado) VALUES ('. $binds .')');
   $cadastro->execute($valores);
}
```

Comment: Consegui ! a saída agora está assim :   Array ( [nome] => Clayton Campos ) Array ( [nome] => Clayton Campos [email] => infogyba@ymail.com ) Array ( [nome] => Clayton Campos [email] => infogyba@ymail.com [telefone] => (21)2481-3232 ) ,como faço agora para inserir cada array num campo da tabela (INSERT) em PDO ?

Comment: eis o código:   $lista = array();
foreach($_POST as $dados => $value) {
$list = explode('_', $value);
$lista[$dados] = $list[0];
print_r($lista).'<br />';
}

Comment: @ClaytonCampos daqui a pouco edito

Comment: @ClaytonCampos sempre são vem os 11  campos?

Comment: oops faltou um , são 12 , são eles: nome,email,telefone,servico,cep,tipo_logradouro,logradouro,numero,complemento,bairro,cidade e estado.serão preenchidos com o valor de array que vem do post,essa é a idéia.

Comment: @ClaytonCampos isso fica dentro do `$list` depois do `explode()` certo?

Comment: não vem antes: $lista = array();
foreach($_POST as $dados => $value) {
$list = explode('_', $value);
$lista[$dados] = $list[0];
print_r($lista).'<br />';
}  o resultado vem de $value

Comment: @ClaytonCampos editada, veja se os valores vão para os campos corretos.

Comment: Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\Loja\test.php on line 108 ( $cadastro->execute($valores);)

Comment: `$valores` tem qtos elementos?

Comment: coloque 13 elementos, por favor.

Comment: @ClaytonCampos algum é vazio? se não basta deixar assim `$binds = str_repeat('?,', 12) .'?';`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40011/discussion-between-clayton-campos-and-rray).